# Redirect old formated URLs for avoid 404 errors

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A few days ago I changed the permalinks on my website from this format: `/index.php/year/month/postName` to `/postName` and I've noticed that I'm getting a lot of 404 errors from external links that retain the old structure.

How can I use `.htaccess` to redirect those who click on `/index.php/year/month/postName` to `/postName`? And thus not to lose those visits.

I have tried with this code but still remains the error:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$3
```

The same with `$4`.

Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/\d{4}/\d\d/([^/]*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1 [R=301,L]
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=El\sCorregidor|hystoriador
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !woocommerce_items_in_cart
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
# Con especificamos cache
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 3 months"
</IfModule>
# FIN
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: "changed the permalinks" - WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ https://www.myweb.com/$3
> ```

This looks "OK". (Although the 1st and 2nd capturing groups are not necessary). However, I suspect you are using WordPress ("permalinks") and have existing mod_rewrite directives in order to route the request through a front-controller, so you should be using mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) for this redirect instead of a mod_alias `RedirectMatch`. (mod_rewrite is always processed before mod_alias, despite the apparent order of the directives in the config file, so you can get unexpected conflicts if you mix the two.)

> The same with $4

`$4` would empty since there is no 4th capturing subpattern in the regex (2nd argument). This suggests the rule is not doing anything - possibly a conflict with other directives.

Try the following instead using mod_rewrite at the **top** of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing mod_rewrite directives:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php/\d{4}/\d\d/([^/]*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm assuming `<year>` (2nd path segment) is always 4 digits and `<month>` (3rd path segment) is 2 digits.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing.

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs later in the file.)

If you are still getting 404s and no redirect then try setting the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

This explicitly permits URLs of the form `/<file>/<path-info>`, eg. `/index.php/<something>`. (Although `.php` files normally allow this by default.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
Yes, indeed, it is a Wordpress. 
I have applied the changes you suggest but they still return 404 page error.
Any more ideas?

Comment: @damargon Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file, with these directives in place.

Comment: I have edited with the htaccess code, thanks